# Flutter: iOS doesn't ask for permissions

Tags: flutter

I have this code showing the Retry button:

```
TextButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                await _checkPermission().then(
                  (hasGranted) {
                    if (hasGranted == PermissionStatus.granted) {
                      refreshContacts();
                    }
                  },
                );
              },

...

Future<PermissionStatus> _checkPermission() async {
    final Permission permission = Permission.contacts;
    final status = await permission.request();
    return status;
  }
```

This always returns:

```
PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied
```

but it doesn't open the permission question again.

Info.plist:

```
<key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app requires access to display the contacts list. This will be used to import contacts automatically if necessary to the app contacts list.</string>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by this issue on its repo: https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/issues/718#event-5560838657

Answer (score 1):

as per the current version of permission handler you need to add contact permission in `Podfile` and `plist` both files make sure you have added this.

Answer (score 0):

If a permission is permanently denied, it can only be enabled from the application settings (bar reinstalling the app). You can use the [`openAppSettings`](https://pub.dev/documentation/permission_handler/latest/permission_handler/openAppSettings.html) function to redirect the user to the settings.